# US Census Tiger/LINE Area Landmarks - what are the airport polygons based on?

Tags: tiger

What are the polygons in the US Census Tiger/Line Area Landmarks file based on?

Specifically, I'm interested in the airport polygons. Are they sourced from a particular gov't agency or the airports themselves (making them "official" in some way), or are they more arbitrary?

The [Landmarks documentation (pg. 4-29)](https://www2.census.gov/geo/pdfs/maps-data/data/tiger/tgrshp2021/TGRSHP2021_TechDoc.pdf) does not provide context for the Census' sources for their polygons.

Comment: If this is open data then I think the place to ask about its compilation is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.